# How can I annotate this complex join in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, join, annotations

Let's say I have the following tables:

```
Locations
================
LocationKey,    LocationName


Employees
================
EmployeeKey,    FirstName,    LastName


EmployeeLocationXRef
================
EmployeeLocationXRefKey,    LocationKey,    EmployeeKey


TimeSheets
=================
TimeSheetKey,    EmployeeLocationXRefKey,    Minutes
```

OK, so as you can see, in order for me to get all of the `TimeSheets` for a `Location` and `Employee`, I can do the following in SQL

```
select
    *
from TimeSheets ts
    join EmployeeLocationXRef ex on (ex.EmployeeLocationXRefKey = ts.EmployeeLocationXRefKey)
    join Locations l on (l.LocationKey = ex.LocationKey)
    join Employees e on (e.EmployeeKey = ex.EmployeeKey)
where
    l.LocationKey = 'xxxx'
    and e.EmployeeKey = 'yyyy'
```

But I have tried every way I can think of to map with (with annotations) in JPA using `@JoinTable`, etc.

Any ideas how this could be done?  Unfortunately, this is a legacy system and the schema cannot be changed.

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention the `EmployeeLocationXRef` entity has not been directly mapped.  Which could be the real problem.  I will see about creating that entity mapping and see if it makes it easier.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything particularly difficult or strange about this schema. There should simply be one entity per table and (unless there are unique constraints):

- a ManyToOne between EmployeeLocationXRef and Location, using a JoinColumn
- a ManyToOne between EmployeeLocationXRef and Employee, using a JoinColumn
- a ManyToOne between Timesheet and EmployeeLocationXRef, using a JoinColumn

(these associations can of course be made bidirectional, or be in the other direction if you prefer so).

The JPQL query would simply be

```
select ts from Timesheet ts
    join ts.employeeXRef ex
    join ex.location l
    join ex.employee e
where
    l.locationKey = 'xxxx'
    and e.employeeKey = 'yyyy'
```

which is a straightforward translation of the SQL query.

Comment: Forgot to mention the `EmployeeLocationXRef` entity has not been mapped.

Comment: Well, that's the problem. It has to be mapped.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  No biggie. We were just hoping to be able to do something like `location.getTimeSheets()`.  I guess we could build a custom getter for that?

Comment: Yes, of course. In queries, you won't be able to hide the EmployeeLocationXRef, though.